# Semantic arguments of nouns

Tags: semantics, adjuncts, thematic-roles, complement

Consider the following NPs:

[1] *an **alcohol** ban* 
[2] *a **cotton** shirt*

Various discussions in [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) would seem to imply the following:

**P:** *alcohol* expresses a semantic argument of the head noun *ban* in [1], while *cotton* does **not** express a semantic argument of the head noun *shirt* in [2]

How can claim **P** be supported?

One explanation:
i. according to CGEL (p. 441), 'complements express semantic arguments of the head noun'.
ii. *alcohol* is a complement in [1], while *cotton* is merely a modifier in [2].
 
iii. thus, **P:** *alcohol* expresses a semantic argument of the head noun *ban* in [1], while *cotton* does not express a semantic argument of the head noun *shirt* in [2].<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>In order to prevent circular reasoning, there must be independent reasons for saying that *alcohol* is a complement in [1] while *cotton* is a modifier in [2] (reasons independent of whether  *alcohol* and *cotton* express semantic arguments of their respective head nouns). And perhaps there are such arguments. For example, CGEL would say this: [1] can be paraphrased as *a ban on alcohol*; in that rephrasing, the preposition *on* is licensed by the noun *ban*; 'The licensing criterion is the most basic criterion for complement status of post-head dependents' (p. 440). And perhaps there is no corresponding story about licensing that can be said about [2].</sup>

But is there any **other** way to establish **P,** a way that does **not** rely on first establishing that *alcohol* is a complement in [1] whereas *cotton* is a modifier in [2]?

Comment: @GregLee Sorry, I don't understand. Why think that *sudden* is an adverb in that phrase? Surely, it's an adjective?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I revised my comment and made it an answer.  If you think "sudden" is an adjective, what do you make of "a sudden cotton shirt"? Part of the nominalization process is to convert adverb modifiers into derived adjectives.

Comment: @ewawe I am trying to see if it is possible to disentangle questions of distinguishing complements vs modifiers from questions about semantic arguments. The link you posted, as best as I can tell, is solely about distinguishing complements from modifiers. For example, it does not even contain the phrase *semantic argument*.  So, my question is this: is it possible to tell that, in [1], *alcohol* is a semantic argument of *ban* without **first** determining that *alcohol* is a complement of *ban*?

Comment: @ewawe (For what it's worth, CGEL does list many of the tests listed in the page you linked, except it doesn't call them 'tests', probably because it says that 'in the NP, [complements and modifiers] are not as clearly differentiated syntactically [as they are in clause structure].')

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now. I'm not really familiar with the concept of "semantic argument" on anything but an informal level. Have you seen it treated as a rigorously defined concept? Informally, "cotton" does not seem like a semantic argument to me because anything can be made of cotton, and being made of cotton is the same predicate for all of those things as it is for a shirt. But an alcohol ban is not "a ban that is made of alcohol", and there's no intuitively easy way to generalize what "alcohol" means in this construction except with very vague wording like "to be about alcohol".

Comment: Then again, I guess compounds can be vague, and I don't know how they fit in relative to the concept of an "argument".

Comment: @ewawe I am not sure what counts as 'rigorously defined concept' in this context. Here is a typical introduction to the concept:

Comment: @ewawe *The standard semantic analysis of the argument–adjunct [a.k.a. complement-modifier] distinction is that an argument [i.e. complement] is a SEMANTIC ARGUMENT of the head, whereas an adjunct is a FUNCTOR or PREDICATE whose argument is the head. To return to our example of (63a) (*Randy chased [the dog]  [in the park]*), *chase* denotes a predicate taking two arguments, one of which is filled by the dog. Hence, the dog is a semantic argument of the chasing event.*

Comment: @ewawe *On the other hand, being or occurring in the park is a predicate taking one argument, which is filled by the chasing event taking place in the park. Hence, the location of the chasing event is a semantic adjunct of the chasing event. To put the standard semantic analysis in the semantic terms used in Table 2.2 in §2.4.2, the chasing event is RELATIONAL and the dog fills one of the semantic roles in the chasing relation. Conversely, being in the park is relational and the chasing event fills the semantic roles in the being-in-the-park relation.*

Comment: @ewawe *As can be seen from this example, one and the same semantic component can be a relation and at the same time be the filler of a role in a relation. In this example, the chasing event is both a relation (one of whose roles is filled by the dog), and the filler of a role in a relation (the being-in-the-park relation). Hence the relation–role filler distinction is relative to the two semantic components in a semantic structure that are being compared by the analyst.*

Comment: @ewawe (source: W. Croft, *Radical Construction Grammar*, pp. 273-274, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ESa_E-q8hbwC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA273&dq=%22The%20standard%20semantic%20analysis%20of%20the%20argument%22&pg=PA273#v=onepage&q=%22The%20standard%20semantic%20analysis%20of%20the%20argument%22&f=false)).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "alcohol" is an argument of the verb "ban" (not the *noun* "ban").  Note the interpretation of "sudden" as adverbial in "a sudden alcohol ban".  The NP is a nominalization of a sentence whose main verb is "ban".

Comment: Like linguisticturn, I'm confused about why "sudden" is described as adverbial in this context. If this is an adverbial interpretation, does "sudden" have any non-adverbial interpretations? Because of its definition, it's hard for me to think of examples where "sudden" is used to modify a noun that cannot be interpreted as referring to an action, and most such nouns have a related verb. (Maybe "sudden darkness" or "sudden heat"?).

Comment: @ewawe, modifiers of verbs are converted to adjectives in the process of nominalization.  It is misleading to characterize "alcohol" as an object of the noun "ban" in the example when actually it is an object of the underlying *verb* "ban".  It would have been an object if the sentence had not been nominalized.

Comment: @ewawe, I don't know how readers figure that out.  I don't do discovery procedures.

Comment: I meant how do linguists/you know that "a (sudden) alcohol ban" is a nominalization of a sentence containing the verb *ban*?

Comment: @GregLee Thank you for your answer; I think I see your point. I do have some follow-up questions, but I fear they would be too tangential to my present post, which is about semantic arguments.

Comment: @ewawe, My contention that "ban" in the example is from the verb "ban" is just my theory of the sentence.  You might have some different theory.  I don't think there is some procedure that gives a determinate answer about whether a NP is a nominalization, but others might differ.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me.

Comment: But "alcohol ban" isn't a valid English VP. How do you see this working as a nominalisation?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Greg Lee clarified that in this kind of nominalization, adverbial modifiers like "suddenly" are converted to the corresponding adjective form; presumably word order can also be adjusted. Maybe compare "reckless mountain climbing", where "mountain" comes before "climbing", even though in a finite VP the usual word order would be "they climb mountains".

Comment: @ewawe "mountain climbing" can be seen as an example of productive incorporation, but I've never heard anyone say "alcohol banning". "The government should not be involved with alcohol banning" is grammatical and makes sense, but I'd be surprised to hear or read a sentence like that in the wild.

Comment: @curiousdannii, The NP "alcohol ban" is from the VP "ban alcohol", with the verb and object in the normal order for a VP.